# Vue3 meta tags aren't updating after passing them to vue-router

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I'm using `vue-router` and `vue3` in my project. The routing works fine, I can switch between pages without a problem but I'm unable to see the meta tags. Looking in the header the meta tags I attached below aren't there. They dont seem to be in the body either. Why aren't they showing up?

router/index.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/find'
  },
  {
    path: '/find',
    name: 'find',
    component: FindGroupComponent,
    meta: {
      title: 'title test',
      metaTags: [{
        name: 'description',
        content: 'description test'
      },
      {
        name: 'keywords',
        content: 'keyword, test'
      },
      {
        name: 'robots',
        content: 'index,follow'
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  }
]

export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```

main.js

```
import { router } from './router'
...
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: The router `meta` option has nothing to do with HTML meta tags.  Vue-meta can help with that but be aware that it will not make your site SEO friendly.  For that you need SSR.  Nuxt is a good option.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create meta tags in your head like that :)

Those "meta" values in ur routes, are just objects where u can store some data.

To create meta tags like u want try use - [VUE META](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-meta)